# Why is the RecyclerView not working when the compiler isn't giving any errors?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Usually, I don't ask questions like these; I do my research and at least am able to identify the problem before asking on StackOverflow. But this time, even after thoroughly researching and looking over my code over and over again, I can't even identify the problem. So I apologize for asking such a broad question.

I have some RecyclerViews in my app (9, to be exact). One of them is working, eight are not. I have looked over my code over and over again, but I can't seem to identify the problem. I'll paste the code for one recycler view and its adapter. This is what my layout for a single element looks like:

[image]

And here is my code for the layout of a single element (I'm just posting it for people to know the ids):

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#0099ff">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".12077"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".87923"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".16908"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".14706"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".37198"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".83"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".13235"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".38235"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_planter"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".61765"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_mark_fulfilled_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".32367"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_mark_fulfilled_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".43961"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".74265"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".96324"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".58696"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".70290"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/left_border"
            android:background="#0099ff"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/left_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#0099ff" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/right_border"
            android:background="#0099ff"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/right_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#0099ff" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/right_guideline_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/order_planter_message_shape" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:civ_shadow="false"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_image_view" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_order"
            android:text="# Trees"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_semibold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="bottom|start"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_order"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_planter"
            android:text="David Malan, $20"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:gravity="bottom|start"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_text_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_order"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_text_view_planter"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mark_fulfilled_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_mark"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_mark_fulfilled_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_mark_fulfilled_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_icon"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/message_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_mark"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline_message_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline_icon"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my code for the adapter of the RecyclerView:

```java
    package com.example.treeapp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class DonorOrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DonorOrdersAdapter.DonorOrdersViewHolder> {
        public String email;
        public static DownloadImageTask downloadImageTask;

        public static class DonorOrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public CircularImageView imageView;
            public TextView orderTextView;
            public TextView planterTextView;
            public ImageView markFulfilledIcon;
            public ImageView messageIcon;

            DonorOrdersViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
                orderTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_order);
                planterTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_planter);
                markFulfilledIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.mark_fulfilled_icon);
                messageIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.message_icon);
                downloadImageTask = new DownloadImageTask(imageView);
            }
        }

        DonorOrdersAdapter(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        List<Integer> orders = MainActivity.database.ordersDao().getOrdersByDonor(email);

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public DonorOrdersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.donor_order, parent, false);

            return new DonorOrdersViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DonorOrdersViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final int current = orders.get(position);
            final String planterEmail = MainActivity.database.ordersDao().getPlanter(current);

            if (MainActivity.database.plantersDao().getImageUrl(planterEmail) != null) {
                downloadImageTask.execute(MainActivity.database.plantersDao().getImageUrl(planterEmail));
            }

            holder.orderTextView.setText(MainActivity.database.ordersDao(  ).getTrees(current) + " trees");
            holder.planterTextView.setText(MainActivity.database.plantersDao().getName(planterEmail) + ", $" +
                                           MainActivity.database.ordersDao().getPayment(current));

            holder.markFulfilledIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent fulfillIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ConfirmPaymentActivity.class);
                    fulfillIntent.putExtra("email", email);
                    fulfillIntent.putExtra("orderId", current);

                    view.getContext().startActivity(fulfillIntent);
                }
            });

            holder.messageIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MessageActivity.class);
                    messageIntent.putExtra("email", email);
                    messageIntent.putExtra("peerEmail", planterEmail);
                    messageIntent.putExtra("archived", 0);

                    view.getContext().startActivity(messageIntent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return orders.size();
        }
    }
```

I am using a SQLite table using the room library. Here is the code for a row of the table:

```java
    package com.example.treeapp;

    import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
    import androidx.room.Entity;
    import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

    @Entity(tableName = "Orders")
    public class Order {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        public int id;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "Donor")
        public String donorEmail;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "Planter")
        public String planterEmail;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "Trees")
        public int trees;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "Payment")
        public int payment;

        @ColumnInfo(name = "Fulfilled")
        public int fulfilled;
    }
```

And here is the code for the Data Access Object:

```java
    package com.example.treeapp;

    import androidx.room.Dao;
    import androidx.room.Query;

    import java.util.List;

    @Dao
    public interface OrdersDao {
        @Query("INSERT INTO Orders (Donor, Planter, Trees, Payment, Fulfilled) VALUES (:donorEmail, :planterEmail, :trees, :payment, 0)")
        void create(String donorEmail, String planterEmail, int trees, int payment);

        @Query("SELECT Donor FROM Orders WHERE id = :id")
        String getDonor(int id);

        @Query("SELECT Planter FROM Orders WHERE id = :id")
        String getPlanter(int id);

        @Query("SELECT Trees FROM Orders WHERE id = :id")
        int getTrees(int id);

        @Query("SELECT Payment FROM Orders WHERE id = :id")
        int getPayment(int id);

        @Query("SELECT Fulfilled FROM Orders WHERE id = :id")
        int getFulfilled(int id);

        @Query("UPDATE Orders SET Fulfilled = 1 WHERE id = :id")
        void markFulfilled(int id);

        @Query("SELECT id FROM Orders WHERE Donor = :donorEmail AND Fulfilled = 0")
        List<Integer> getOrdersByDonor(String donorEmail);

        @Query("SELECT id FROM Orders WHERE Planter = :planterEmail AND Fulfilled = 0")
        List<Integer> getOrdersToPlanter(String planterEmail);

        @Query("SELECT id FROM Orders WHERE Fulfilled = 0")
        List<Integer> getUnfulfilledOrders();
    }
```

And here is my code for the activity in which the recycler views are used:

```java
    package com.example.treeapp;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class DonorOrdersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private String email;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor_orders);

            email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            adapter = new DonorOrdersAdapter(email);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
    }
```

If anyone is able to figure out what's wrong with my RecyclerViews, please tell me.

**EDIT: ** I have tested that my database actually contains the orders by logging data from the orders table.

Comment: To pinpoint the bug, I would mock the datasource in the adapter first if I were you. So `Adapter` will not connect directly to the database but rely on `List<Order>`. Afterwards we can proceed whether the view or the database code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: As @shinwan stated, you should restructure your adapter to allow you to test it it with mock data. Also, is there a reason you're accessing the database through a reference to MainActivity?

Comment: @SammyT I just declared the database as a static variable in the MainActivity to make life easier for me

Comment: First of all you are accessing db on main thread, that's not good. Why don' you put breakpoints inside getItemCount(), oncreateViewHolder(), onBindViewHolder() methods and run in debug mode, that should definitely help identifying the issue. Mb your getitemCount () method is returning 0

Comment: To help analyse the issue please post the layout where the recyclerView is being layouted, also try setting a fixed height for your item Layout at first (before we start going throw it) and set some eye-catchy background to find out if it's being displayed at the first place

Comment: Also add some Log messages in `onBindViewHolder` to find out which items are being added to the recyclerView

Comment: @Rinat Thanks a lot. I logged the orders.size() in getItemCount() and found out that it was zero. Then I made orders an attribute of the class and assigned its value in the constructor. This solved my problem. Please answer this question so I can award the bounty.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) i added an answer. I will edit it later to be more explicit. Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If getItemCount() returns zero RV wont inflate any viewHolders. Usually if nothing is shown in Rv, putting breakpoints or logging will help identifying the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you see your logcat, you can see `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`. So the solution is change this :

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

to this :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this was not the issue. My orders list was not loading; when I initialized my orders list in the constructor, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not a best solution  but  please specify adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

im not so professional but why not you are using Log? in adapter under onbindviewholder you should log.d(email) you are sending for you activity and also log the data that you are trying to get from sql using this email, by doing this you will become sure of if the data is in adapter or not. if the data is present its means there is a problem with Recyclerview View, means data is good to go but recylerview is not able to show the data to user. else obviously you are not getting the data right.

```
 FilenameSimpleAdapter listAdapter = new FilenameSimpleAdapter(listfilenames,MapsActivity.this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

That is not something special but we are just changing that how will recycler view display the data.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I already posted in the question that I have logged the data from my database, so I know that there is already data in the database.